# AWS Build a Serverless Web Application WildRydes Authentication Error when trying to create a new account on the app

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, serverless, aws-serverless

I'm working on one of the AWS [build a serverless app projects](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-serverless-web-app-lambda-apigateway-s3-dynamodb-cognito/module-2/). Its the project for the WildRydes unicorn rides.

Im stuck on Module 2: User Management.

[Authentication Error Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/259r7.png)

I get  "Authentication Error" when trying to create a new account on the app? I followed along every step but still get this error. I even tried manually creating a group in Cognito and changing the details in the config.js file but I still get the same Authentication Error on the App.

I had tried just following along the official tutorial:
https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-serverless-web-app-lambda-apigateway-s3-dynamodb-cognito/module-2/

But I had trouble with the tutorial itself so I followed along someone's video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GPme1i1VyQQ

Is there another file that also needs to be configured? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

In the *`js/cognito-auth.js`* file

```
function toUsername(email) {
    return email.replace('@', '-at-');
}
```

Update the *toUsername()* function:

```
function toUsername(email) {
    return email;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ankit. I appreciate the response. Will try this!